# How to render a column with jQuery dataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using jQuery dataTables to fetch data from the server.

here is my code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "Device/AjaxHandler",
            "bProcessing": true,
            "aoColumns": [
            { "sName": "AccountCode" },               
            { "sName": "User" },             
            { "sName": "Signal Strength"           
              "render": renderSignal(data)
            }                ]
        });

        function renderSignal(val) {
            return '<p>' + val + '</p>';
        }
    });
</script>
```

This doesn't work, but I have the feeling it is a syntax error.

Im not sure if `render` is the correct function name to use.

What I want to do, is take a value 1-3 and then display a different image for each value.
So I want to define that columns layout in my `render` function.

Comment: check your firefox console for JS errors.

Comment: I just fixed it. Apparently it has to be `fnRender` any idea why that is? whats the fn mean?

Comment: fn => Function. Datatable convention.

Comment: First of all, you need a comma after `"sName": "Signal Strength"`, also, what version of datatables are you using? The render event was called `fnRender` in versions below 1.9.4 I think.

Comment: You are missing a comma after "Signla Strength" in this code

Comment: version 1.10.2 is the version im using. thanks for the comma as well.

Comment: Here is the documentation: [link](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns#fnRender) So I believe the `mRender` would be the best choice for the future.

Comment: @ReGdYN that api is exactly what i was looking for thanks a mill.

Comment: im getting `data is not defined` do i have to do something else? how do i specify that `data` is the json response from the server?

Comment: If you're using `sAjaxSource`, you need to use `aaData` as the json source. [http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side#sAjaxSource](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side#sAjaxSource)